# Is there anyway to give a variable a value FOR A CERTAIN AMOUNT OF TIME (java)

Tags: java, javafx

So im writing a simple 2d javafx game and a thought just came into my head.
Can i give a boolean (or any variable type for that matter) a value for a select amount of time.

If its possible ,how would it look like

Comment: This is C# but ought to give you some ideas. [How to reset an application variable daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246998/how-to-reset-an-application-variable-daily)

Answer (score 1):

Why not a `TimeLine` ?
Suppose you want to change during about 2 seconds a `String foo` field for an object referenced by a `myObject` variable declared as `MyObject`.

```
myObject.setTemporaryValueForFooField("special value");
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
        Duration.millis(2000),
        ae -> myObject.reuseOriginalValueForFooField()));
timeline.play();
```

`setTemporaryValueForFooField(String)` makes a copy of the current value of the `foo` field in the current instance and assign to it the temporary value.
`reuseOriginalValueForFooField()` reassigns the `foo` field with the original value as the duration is reached.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. You *could* use an [`AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html), a [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Timer.html) (a [`TimerTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/TimerTask.html)) and a simple loop. Like,

```
AtomicBoolean ab = new AtomicBoolean(true);
Timer t = new Timer(); // <-- The Timer
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ab.set(false);
    }
}, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5)); // <-- once in five seconds.
while (ab.get()) { // <-- while the boolean is true
    System.out.println("It's true");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
t.cancel(); // <-- don't forget to end the Timer.
```

Which prints "It's true" ~ five times.